# After the google sheets v4 update, how do you index through the columns and rows separately?

Tags: google-sheets, google-api

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get

They never specify in documentation, as far as I can tell, on how to go through a row or column only. even with all the money grubbing v4 has now implemented, I still have no choice but to use it for early testing. They wrapped this in so much protocol for tracking your api key so they can limit/charge, that it's not as simple as specifying {A+i} etc anymore. The json formatting is different now.. How do I simply index through the column, then if i get a match, look through the row. (playerID, then check the skills name and levels etc)? is there a code snippet or a reference on how to check row and column independently?? Thank you.

Comment: PS, I'm using it on Unity so, CS (Can't beliee I forgot to mention it!)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.